# Scala agg count function recursive error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to filter my dataframe to find duplicates based on what should be a unique combination of id/day. To do this I wrote the following code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val count = equip
  .groupBy("cust_key", "Time_stamp")
  .agg(count(lit(1)).alias("count")).where("count">1)
```

But I get an error:

> recrusive value count needs type.

I also tried this where instead of lit(1) I used count("cust_key") and got the same error. I have tried looking this up on here but the answers I see are mostly geared towards UDF it looks like. I know the answer is probably something really simple and I'm going to feel dumb for not figuring it out but I can't make it work. Using spark 2.0

Comment: Name the variable `count` as something else? It conflicts with the `count` function, I think.

Comment: Alternatively, use the fully-qualified name of the function `count` so that it won't conflict with the value `count`: `.agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.count(lit(1)).alias("count"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try the below (with `$`):

```
import spark.implicits.StringToColumn

val count = equip
 .groupBy("cust_key", "Time_stamp")
 .agg(count(lit(1)).alias("count")).where($"count" > 1)
```